# Joomla First Component

Tags: joomla, joomla-component

I'm interested in developing a joomla component. My question is.. how to start up things ?

I can build a basic structure, zip it and install it. But is this the right way to start ? I will have to add additional files while developing so I don't understand what are the development steps and procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good place to start is to use this tutorial: http://www.joomladevuser.com/tutorials/components

They use the MVC method which is the best and most practical way to develop a component. From there I guess whatever requirements you need for your component you will learn by searching or asking your way through it on either google or here on StackOverflow. We are all here to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very nice beginner tutorial [Developing a MVC Component For Joomla](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1)

And here is how to properly set up your work station for Joomla development [Setting Up Work Station](http://docs.joomla.org/Setting_up_your_workstation_for_Joomla!_development)

Answer (score 0):

You can build the skeleton (and probably 99% of you admin functionality) using the [Component Creator](http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/)